# What is the name convention of binding a complex ViewModels?

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-mvc-4, binding

I have these two ***`ViewModels`***

```
public class AboutViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public override long Id { get; set; }        
    public override string PageTitle { get; set; }        
    public override string TitleDescription { get; set; }        
    public override string ContentTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual AboutItemViewModel AboutItem { get; set; }
}

public class AboutItemViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]        
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileToUpload { get; set; }
}
```

***`Here is my controller:`***

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken, HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(long? siteid, long? cid, AboutViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "About", new { siteid = ViewData["siteid"], cid = ViewData["cid"] },FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal rtl", autocomplete = "off" }))
{
     <div class="controls">
       <input type="file" name="FileToUpload" id="FileToUpload" style="margin-right: -9px;">
     </div>
     <div class="controls">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(o => o.AboutItem.FileToUpload, "", new { id = "spanfile", @class = "alert alert-block alert-error span3 pull-right", style = "margin-right: 160px;" })
     </div>   
     <div class="control-group pull-left">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large" data-toggle="button">Save</button>
    </div> 
}
```

How to bind the file to **`FileToUpload`** to stop returning me a null?

*`Except:`*
If I put it in the main ***`AboutViewModel`*** than it's returns a correct value.

Comment: damn, man, looks good. you have the parts I always look for: **HttpPostedFileBase name matches file name, and enctype = "multipart/form-data"** if something else is missing, I don't see it

Comment: Hi man, I have looked for every thing, I thought I missed something, apparently I didn't :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the FileToUpload property is in the AboutItem proprety, which is a class property of the parent ViewModel, you need to preface the name of your input element with the property it came from.  That's a long way of saying that the name of your file input should be AboutItem.FileToUpload.

```
<input type="file" name="AboutItem.FileToUpload" id="AboutItem_FileToUpload" />
```

This should take care of the model binding for you.  Additionally, you can test this by using an HTML helper on on of the other properties of the AboutItem class.  For instance:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.AboutItem.Id)
```

This should render in the HTML

```
<input type="text" name="AboutItem.Id" id="AboutItem_Id />
```

**EDIT**

Apparently the id attribute will be rendered with an underscore instead of a dot.  However, since the ID attribute is not used in model binding, it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Cool! It's works very weird though I've tried it without an id, and it didn't worked. Very Weird!